# Clickhouse. How to create a column which preserves the last value from another column?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm trying to figure out how one can make in Clickhouse a column with the name "**What I want**" in the table below:

| Category | Row Number | What I have | What I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| B | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| B | 7 | 0 | 3 |
| A | 8 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 9 | 0 | 2 |

There are two categories A and B.
And I want B category to 'remember' the latest value from A category.

There's a column by which all records are ordered: Row Number.

I've found a function **arrayFill** which looks promising but unfortunately it isn't supported by my version of server (19.14.11.16) and there's no chance it'll be updated soon.

I guess there's should be some trick with clickhouse arrays. But I didn't manage to find a way. Is there any clickhouse-ninja who could give me a hint how to deal with it?

p.s. In fact B category isn't zero filled but I provide it just to simplify a little my problem.

Comment: It's doable with arrays, with neighbor, with window functions. The problem it's unclear how to understand what do you mean by "latest", rows are unordered in SQL.

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, I forget to say that there's a column on which all records are ordered. In my particular case there are two such columns user_id and timestamp but let's imagine there's only one which I called Row Number.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table z(c String, rn Int64, hv Int64) Engine=Memory;

insert into z values ('A',1,0)('A',2,1)('B',3,0)('B',4,0)('A',5,3)('B',6,0)('B',7,0)('A',8,2)('B',9,0);

select (arrayJoin(flatten(arrayMap( j -> arrayMap(m -> if(m.1 = 'B', (m.1, m.2, ga1[j-1][-1].3), m) , ga1[j]),
    arrayEnumerate(arraySplit(k,i -> ga[i].1 <> ga[i-1].1 , (groupArray( (c, rn, hv) ) as ga), arrayEnumerate(ga)) as ga1)))) as r).1 _c,
    r.2 _rn, r.3 _n
from (select * from z order by rn)


┌─_c─┬─_rn─┬─_n─┐
│ A  │   1 │  0 │
│ A  │   2 │  1 │
│ B  │   3 │  1 │
│ B  │   4 │  1 │
│ A  │   5 │  3 │
│ B  │   6 │  3 │
│ B  │   7 │  3 │
│ A  │   8 │  2 │
│ B  │   9 │  2 │
└────┴─────┴────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Trying figure out how it works )